# How to scale up the screen where the style 'position: absolute' applied components is placed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I scale up the screen when the code looks like this?

```css
.drawing-board {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  /* transform: scale(2, 2); */
}

.drawing-board .box-1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 90px;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}

.drawing-board .box-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="drawing-board">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

At first, I thought that applying `transform: scale()` to all elements would scale up

Do you have any examples related to this?

Comment: Off-topic: you can use just one value: `transform: scale(2);` 

Comment: Your question - as it stands - is not comprehensible. Your elements are scaled. OK. What was your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the `transform` to the parent, *everything* is scaled, including the distance between the children (see below). If your problem is that some parts disappear/overflow to the left, you can use `transform-origin` to define the "root" for your transform:

```css
.drawing-board {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.drawing-board .box-1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 90px;
}

.drawing-board .box-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawing-board">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```